# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation"clienti_id_seq" does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to learn hibernate framework with making a simple program that push a class **Cliente** into a table on postgres, The error that returns is as follow:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation "clienti_id_seq" does not exist
```

This is my database by PGAdmin (sorry for imgur i can't upload picture directly) https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5XQo.png

This is the class **Cliente**

```
public class Cliente {

private long clienteId;
private String clienteNome;
private String clienteCognome;
private String clienteTelefono;
private String clienteMail;
private String clientePermesso;
private long clienteCommessa;

public long getClienteId() {
    return clienteId;
}

public void setClienteId(long clienteId) {
    this.clienteId = clienteId;
}

public String getClienteNome() {
    return clienteNome;
}

public void setClienteNome(String clienteNome) {
    this.clienteNome = clienteNome;
}
public String getClienteCognome() {
    return clienteCognome;
}

public void setClienteCognome(String clienteCognome) {
    this.clienteCognome = clienteCognome;
}

 public String getClienteTelefono() {
    return clienteTelefono;
}

public void setClienteTelefono(String clienteTelefono) {
    this.clienteTelefono = clienteTelefono;
}

 public String getClienteMail() {
    return clienteMail;
}

public void setClienteMail(String clienteMail) {
    this.clienteMail = clienteMail;
}

 public String getClientePermesso() {
    return clientePermesso;
}

public void setClientePermesso(String clientePermesso) {
    this.clientePermesso = clientePermesso;
}

 public long getClienteCommessa() {
    return clienteCommessa;
}

public void setClienteCommessa(long clienteNome) {
    this.clienteCommessa = clienteCommessa;
}

}
```

This is my **mapping** file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="beans.Cliente" table="Clienti">
    <id name="clienteId" type="integer" column="id" >

        <generator class="sequence"> 
            <param name="sequence">CLIENTI_ID_seq</param>            
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="clienteNome" column="nome" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property name="clienteCognome" column="cognome" type="string">            
    </property>
        <property name="clienteTelefono" column="telefono" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property name="clienteMail" column="mail" type="string">            
 </property>
        <property name="clientePermesso" column="permesso" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property name="clienteCommessa" column="commessa" type="string">            
</property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the **hibernate cfg.xml** file, the information about url pass and user are correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration   DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:postgres</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Georilievi</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">Fabio1990</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


<mapping resource="Clienti.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the main file, here i create an istance of Cliente, and try to push in the postgres database

```
package main;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import beans.Cliente;

public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args){
    // Create a configuration instance
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    // Provide configuration file
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    // Build a SessionFactory
    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build());
    // Get current session, current session is already associated with Thread
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    // Begin transaction

    session.getTransaction().begin();

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.setClienteNome("Fabio");
    cliente.setClienteCognome("Tramontana");
    cliente.setClienteTelefono("3343052346");
    cliente.setClienteMail("info.tramontanafabio@gmail.com");
    cliente.setClientePermesso("admin");
    cliente.setClienteCommessa(0);
    // Save*/
    session.save(cliente);
    // Commit, calling of commit will cause save an instance of employee
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

thanks all of you for helping me, i don't understand the error, i think it is in the declaration of the generator.

Comment: pgAdmin shows part of the sequence-name in UPPERcase. Only use lower case to avoid issues like this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however the problem still remain after i used lowercase in any declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try changing the generator class from sequence to identity and see. I guess the issue is the auto generation of IDs.

See these links:
http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateidgeneratorelement.shtml
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property

Comment: thank you for the answer, I read your link and I tried to change the generator class, and now the error change too in "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation"clienti" does not exist", but it doesn't make sense because the relation is autogenerated by Netbeans's mapping file wizard so i think it see the relation

Comment: Are you creating your own schema or creating the tables in the public schema? Referencing tables which are in another schema other than the public requires one to use the convention schemaname.tablename when referencing a table.

Comment: i've resolved the problem, the error was in the type declaration for the id column, on postgres this column have serial type, so in the map clas i must give it "java.lang.Long" type"
Thanks all for the help!